# (.NET Maui) How can I tell when a sub-page returns?

Tags: c#, .net, navigation, maui

I have a newbie .NET Maui development question. I have a page that invokes another page, and when that sub-page ends I want to do something... it is a details page kind of thing, for editing. And when it returns, I want to do something with the data that it edited. I've searched and cannot find a way of notifying a parent page when the child page finishes.

Right now I am still working with test pages, but once I know how to do it, I'll use what I learned in the app. So, I have the following code in my parent page to navigate to the details page.

```
private async void NavigateToPage()
{
    MyItem item = _myItemList.Where(x => x.KeyString == "1958").First();
    _SharedService.Add<MyItem> ("SharedServiceItemKey", item);

    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => { await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new TestPage(_SharedService, item), true); });
 }
```

That's how the details page is called, and it works fine. Next, the details page returns in the following manner.

```
private async void NavigateBack()
{
    _SharedService.Add<MyItem>("SharedServiceReturnItemKey", _item);
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
}
```

Everything works fine as it is, the page is called and returns as it should, and the shared data seems to be there. What I'm missing is some notification that the test page is finished and has passed the data back so that the calling page can do something with it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may also try using [Navigation events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0#navigation-events), which is fired when navigation is about to be performed. From ```ShellNavigatingEventArgs``` you could get the current or target page.

Answer (score 0):

In Maui, you can use [Back button behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0#back-button-behavior) to achieve this.

Back button appearance and behavior can be redefined by setting the `BackButtonBehavior` attached property to a `BackButtonBehavior` object.

The following code shows an example of redefining back button appearance and behavior:

```
<ContentPage ...>    
    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior Command="{Binding BackCommand}"
                            IconOverride="back.png" />   
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```